# How to define custom keywords auto-indentation behavior in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: matlab, sublimetext, sublimetext3

The syntax highlighting for Matlab in Sublime Text 3 is out of date. Many keywords, e.g., *classdef*, *properties*, etc, are not supported.

After some searching on the internet, I've managed to add custom keywords and make the syntax highlighting work by editing the *Matlab.tmLanguage* file. But I cannot find a way to modify the auto-indenting behavior.

Take the keyword *while* as an example. When I type *while something* and hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, the cursor will move to the next line and automatically indent for one level. I want the exact behavior happen to *classdef* too. How to do this in Sublime Text 3?

Thank you!

**EDIT** The question does not have to be restricted to Matlab. You could see it as a general question about **customized keyword auto-indenting in ST3**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I did this, and I'm on an older version of SublimeText, so this answer may not be exactly correct - but hopefully it will lead you in the right direction.

In the folder SublimeText\Data\Packages\Matlab, as well as `Matlab.tmLanguage` there should be a file `Indent.tmPreferences`. In this file, there should be a section `<key>increaseIndentPattern</key>`, containing a list of MATLAB keywords. You should be able to add extra entries to the list, such as `classdef|properties|methods|enumeration|events`, and (if you have Parallel Computing Toolbox) `parfor|spmd` as well.

PS you could also contact MathWorks support, and ask them to get a friendly developer with some spare time to contribute a modern, up-to-date implementation of syntax highlighting, indentation etc to SublimeText. They already do that for emacs with Eric Ludlam's [MATLAB mode for emacs](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/104-edit-m-files-in-emacs) - why not SublimeText too?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Too bad that I need 15 reputation to vote you up.